# PhpStorm Git file adding issue

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

**Problem:** "Git > Add" doesn't seem to do anything, and "Git > Commit File" says "No changes detected", when git from the command line sees changes and can commit/push files.

**Details:**
I'm using PhpStorm 2017.3.2 (evaluating it) on OSX .

I have a project that I've clone from GitHub. Git is configured. I can call `git status` from the terminal and it lists several files that have been changed and are not staged for a commit yet. My `.git/config` file lists a remote "origin" at github. Both "github" and "git integration" plugins are enabled in the "Preferences -> Plugins" menu. Under "Version Control > GitHub" my connection is configured and tested as working properly. Under "Version Control > Git", the git interaction is properly configured and tested as working.

If I change a file in my project (the file is shown in blue now) and I right click and select "Git > Add" nothing happens. If I do "Git > Commit File" a dialog box pops up and says "no changes detected". Under the "Changes" tab at the bottom, under "local" no files are listed. However, if I call `git status` from the terminal, the changed files are listed, and I can add, commit, and push them just fine.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get PhpStorm to play nicely with git. Any suggestions?

Screenshots:

```
modified file: https://ibb.co/cHmF4w
when copying: https://ibb.co/eq86Bb (add to git checkbox not visible)
file color: https://ibb.co/f842jw
add to git is disabled: https://ibb.co/keu2jw
```

Answer (score 0):

A blue file name means the file is already tracked by git and has changes. If a file is unknown to git, it's name will be red. If it is a new file that has been added but not committed, then it's name will be green.

Comment: I know that. When i copy a file into project directory or I paste the file into the project, it does not load it and the file color does not change

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Remove .gitignore file on user folder.

```
rm -f "/Users/username/.gitignore"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I solved id
File->Settings->Version Control->Ignored Files
empty list of files and directories